# Is $\int_0^{+\infty}\sin{x}dx$ equal to $\int_0^{+\infty}dk\int_0^{+\infty}e^{(-kx)}x\sin{x}dx$?

Tags: integration

I have read a method for calculating $\int_{0^+}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin{x}}{x}dx$ in a book and then confused with whether the $\int_{0^+}^{+\infty}\sin{x}dx=-\cos{x}|_{0^+}^{+\infty}$ could be integrated with this method.

This method use the result : $\int_{0^+}^{+\infty}e^{-kx}dk=\frac{1}{x},\text{when}\ x\gt{0}$.

So,
$$\int_{0^+}^{+\infty}\sin{x}dx=\int_{0^+}^{+\infty}dk\int_{0^+}^{+\infty}e^{(-kx)}x\sin{x}dx$$

$$\int_{0^+}^{+\infty}e^{(-kx)}x\sin{x}dx=-\frac{1}{k}e^{-kx}x\sin{x}|_{0^+}^{+\infty}+\frac{1}{k}\int_{0^+}^{+\infty}e^{-kx}d(x\sin{x})\\=-\frac{1}{k}e^{-kx}x\sin{x}|_{0^+}^{+\infty}+\frac{1}{k}\int_{0^+}^{+\infty}e^{-kx}\sin{x}dx+\frac{1}{k}\int_{0^+}^{+\infty}e^{-kx}x\cos{x}dx$$

$$\int_{0^+}^{+\infty}e^{-kx}x\cos{x}dx=-\frac{1}{k}e^{-kx}x\cos{x}|_{0^+}^{+\infty}+\frac{1}{k}\int_{0^+}^{+\infty}e^{-kx}d(x\cos{x})\\=-\frac{1}{k}e^{-kx}x\cos{x}|_{0^+}^{+\infty}+\frac{1}{k}\int_{0^+}^{+\infty}e^{-kx}\cos{x}dx-\frac{1}{k}\int_{0^+}^{+\infty}e^{-kx}x\sin{x}dx$$

$$e^{-kx}x\sin{x}|_{x \rightarrow 0^+}^{x \rightarrow+\infty}=0,\text{when } k\gt 0$$

$$e^{-kx}x\cos{x}|_{x \rightarrow 0^+}^{x \rightarrow+\infty}=0,\text{when } k\gt 0$$

$$\int_{0^+}^{+\infty}e^{-kx}\sin{x}dx=\frac{1}{k^2+1},\text{when } k\gt 0$$

$$\int_{0^+}^{+\infty}e^{-kx}\cos{x}dx=\frac{k}{k^2+1},\text{when } k\gt 0$$

$$\int_{0^+}^{+\infty}e^{(-kx)}x\sin{x}dx=\frac{2k}{(k^2+1)^2}$$

$$\int_{0^+}^{+\infty}\sin{x}dx=\int_{0^+}^{+\infty}\frac{2k}{(k^2+1)^2}dk=1\neq-\cos{x}|_{x\rightarrow 0^+}^{x \rightarrow +\infty}$$

I could not figure out why not different method produce same result.

Comment: You should be clear on which notion of integral (or summation method) you are using to give a meaning and value to your integral. In this case, the usual improper Riemann integral or Lebesgue integral fail to give a value, since $\int_{0}^{R} \sin x \, dx = 1 - \cos R$ does not converge as $R \to \infty$. On the other hand, it is both Cesaro summable and Abel summable with the common value $1$. It is not surprising that two notions give different answers. Also your computation can be justified in both summability sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the limit
$$\lim_{t\to\infty} \cos(t)$$
does not exist, so neither does
$$\int_0^\infty \sin(x)dx = \lim_{t\to\infty}\int_0^t\sin(x)dx = \lim_{t\to\infty}\left( 1-\cos(t)\right)$$
Therefore, you cannot apply [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) to interchange the order of integration.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't review your solution but with Laplace transform we can show that for a function $f(t)$ with Laplace transform $F(s)$ we have
$$\int_0^\infty F(s)ds=\int_0^\infty \dfrac{f(t)}{t}dt$$
if you apply this formula for $f(t)=t\sin t$ you will find the result easily!